# Event time in c# kafka client

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

How can I add event time to the kafka messages produced to the topic. I found that we can use KAFKA_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE but not sure how to use it on confluent.kafka v0.9.4

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 0.9.4 branch hasn't been touched in 3 years. I suggest you upgrade.

Secondly, the Message class [has a `Timestamp` field](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/MessageMetadata.cs#L30) which can be set